# не работает overflow:hidden у body и html на iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, веб-программирование, вёрстка

есть событие на открытие модального окна. при открытии окна у html и body должен блокироваться скролл (используем `overflow:hidden`), но он не работает именно у iPhone и у стандартного браузера xiaomi (возможно, не работает где-то ещё, не проверяли). на обычных браузерах андроида работает точно

Пример кода появления `overflow:hidden`

```
$('.product_btn, .social_callback').click(function () {
    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

Испробовали варианты `position: fixed;` и `position: relative;`

Так же задавали `height:100%;`

Либо скролл у body работал, как и раньше, либо скролл блокировался, но при этом перебрасывало на самый верх страницы. Такой вариант нам не подходит.

Как сделать так, чтобы этот скролл блокировался у body, но при этом не перебрасывало на самый верх страницы, как это происходит при `height: 100%;`?

Comment: Честно говоря, варианты есть, но они все ужасные. Совет со стороны: забыть про эту фишку на iOS.

Comment: @NeedHate можешь показать эти варианты?